# Crm 4 event log warnings. CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-3

I am looking for a solution on the following issue. Any suggestions will be very welcomed! Thank you in advance.

Background: We just upgraded MS Crm 3 to Crm 4

Question: 
Every time when a user tries to save a new record or an update of a record. A warning will be logged into Event Viewer --> Application. It happens to all entities.

For example: 
1. I am doing some updates on the contact form "http://localhost:5555/CAMELOT-DEV/sfa/conts/edit.aspx?id={488FF696-4F8C-DE11-AC94-00505698306E}#"
2. Click save
3. I will find a warning message in Event Viewer --> Application
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter 'type=2' in Request.QueryString on page /default.aspx
The raw request was 'GET /default.aspx?type=2&typename=contact&id={488FF696-4F8C-DE11-AC94-00505698306E}&orgname=CAMELOT-DEV&userlcid=1033&orglcid=1033/default.aspx' called from "http://localhost:5555/CAMELOT-DEV/sfa/conts/edit.aspx?id={488FF696-4F8C-DE11-AC94-00505698306E}". 
4. The record is saved fine despite of the warning.

Details:
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event 
Event ID:   1309
Date:       8/09/2009
Time:       9:42:58 a.m.
User:       N/A
Computer:   MYCOMPANYDEV02
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 8/09/2009 9:42:58 a.m. 
Event time (UTC): 7/09/2009 9:42:58 p.m. 
Event ID: 117f3eff7dff438e9862e0767b14de3f 
Event sequence: 1358 
Event occurrence: 24 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-128967648198441643 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft CRM Server\CRMWeb\ 
    Machine name: GFSGWGTNDEV02

Process information: 
    Process ID: 264 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter 'type=2' in Request.QueryString on page /default.aspx
The raw request was 'GET /default.aspx?type=2&typename=contact&id={488FF696-4F8C-DE11-AC94-00505698306E}&orgname=CAMELOT-DEV&userlcid=1033&orglcid=1033/default.aspx' called from http://localhost:5555/CAMELOT-DEV/sfa/conts/edit.aspx?id={488FF696-4F8C-DE11-AC94-00505698306E}.

Request information: 
    Request URL: "http://localhost:5555/default.aspx?type=2&typename=contact&id={488FF696-4F8C-DE11-AC94-00505698306E}&orgname=CAMELOT-DEV&userlcid=1033&orglcid=1033/default.aspx" 
    Request path: /default.aspx 
    User host address: 127.0.0.1 
    User: CAMELOT\Kelvin_Shen 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 6 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ParameterFilter.ValidateParameter(Page page, ArrayList parameterCollection, String key, String value, String collectionName, EntityType pageEntityType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ParameterFilter.ValidateParameters(Page page, EntityType pageEntityType, Boolean alwaysEnableParameterChecking)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ParameterFilter.ValidateParameters(Page page, EntityType pageEntityType)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppPage.ValidatePageParameters()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppPage.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find the cause.

We have an iframe on the form. The problem is the URL property of the iframe is set to "\" rather than about:blank.

So just change the value for iframe URL to about:blank and problem solved.

Cheers